# Azure IoT Hub MQTT device and device twin changes

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I have a device that is an mqtt client to Azure IoT Hub and want the devcie to be notified about changes/updates in the device-twin for that device.

I've successfully connected and updated the **reported** value in the *device-twin* from the device but can't seem to get an event when I change some of the **desired** properties in the *device-twin* from the Azure shell (https://shell.azure.com/) using a command like this:

`az iot hub device-twin update -n <myIotHubBame> -d <myDeviceId> --set properties.desired='{"foo":"bar"}'`

On the device I've tried subscribing to `$iothub/twin/res/#` and `devices/<myDeviceId>/messages/devicebound/#` but am not receiving any message after issuing the **az** command from the Azure shell.

I tried also setting a *message route* with **Data Source = Twin Change Events** and **Endpoint = event** but still no message being received in the device.

Anyone has a suggestion on how to get notification to the device when properties in the device-twin changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQTT device needs to subscribe on the following topic

```
$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/desired/#
```

for receiving a notification changes on the device twin desired properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I've tried to subscribe on the device to this topic without any success.

Do I need to setup some *message routing* in the Iot Hub or should I be able to test this directly with an Azure shell command like mentioned before:
`az iot hub device-twin update -n <myIotHubBame> -d <myDeviceId> --set properties.desired='{"foo":"bar"}'`

Comment: once your device is connected, subscribed on that topic and the device has a handler for receiver, your device is ready to receive a notification changes on the desired properties. You can easy use an azure portal for testing.

Comment: Thanks again for you response, I've tried this topic again and strangely it worked now. Obviously I messed up somehow before